# Microsoft Query syntax to extract domains from subdomains

Tags: excel, syntax, ms-query

If your table has a row like:

```
sub.test.com
test.com
foo.bar.co.nz
hey.co.uk
www.stackoverflow.com
```

Then what do you put in your SELECT SQL syntax to get just pure domains in Excel:

```
test.com
test.com
bar.co.nz
hey.co.uk
stackoverflow.com
```

?

In other words, what do I put instead of "something" below?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking for a SQL query here, or something else?

Comment: Yes, SQL query for  Microsoft Query. I've added a screenshot to clarify it.